# Do we need to use parametrization for unit testing if we are 'setting mock objects' to different inputs but not using them in our code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, parametrize

Here is the unit test I have written:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('mock_finfo, mock_download_result',
                         [
                          ({'ready': False},
                           None)
                         ])
@mock.patch('jobserve.tasks.parsing_pipeline._pcontrol.pass1_parse')
@mock.patch('jobserve.tasks.parsing_pipeline.download_single_file_from_s3', return_value=None)
def test_parseable_files_pass1_force_False(mock_download_single_file_from_s3,
                                           mock_pass1_parse, mock_finfo, download_result):

    mock_parseable_files.return_value = mock_finfo

    parser_code = 'lse'
    data_file_group = 'equities2'
    dte = 20190501
    parser_extra_params = {'force': True}


    try:
        pass1(parser_code)

    except ValueError as ve:
        assert False, f"pass1 raised a ValueError {ve}"
```

In the above example, if I do not use `mock_download_result` anywhere in my code, however I want to run the test cases with potentially different inputs of `mock_download_result`. Is this the correct way to strucutre the unit test?

Comment: It is OK, but why `parametrize` here, if you use only one value? `parametrize` is useful if you use, say, `{'ready': False}, None` and `{'ready': True}, 'content'` as two options to test with same expectations.

Comment: Thanks @SUTerliakov, yes you are right- in the actual code there are many more values, I should have left at least 2 in as an example, as I do understand this is the whole point of parametrizing. But if we only have 1 value, is there another way to set the unit test?

Comment: If `mock_download_result` isn't used, then running your test with different values for it is pointless. What happes if you simply removed it? Does the test outcome differ at all with it?

Comment: Maybe what you need instead is `usefixtures` if the test isn't using the fixture at all, but it affects the test outcome: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest-mark-usefixtures

Comment: I like `pytest-mock` package for that. If you have 1 value, request `mocker` fixture (provided by that package) and use it as usual `unittest.mock` module (like `mocker.patch('some.dotted.path', spec=..., return_value=..., ...)`). And parametrize is pointless for single test, so just mock these values at the beginning of test function.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it work with `mock.patch`- makes so much more sense using this.